# Public facebook page feed

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to add last 4 news to my website, fetching them from facebook API. There is no facebook login on website or anything like that. I've created FB APP and used `FB.api()` function to fetch news, but APIs need `access_token`, which should not be seen publicly, but news fetching is on frontend (js). Is there a way to obtain some other access_token only for reading public news which can be public?

My code (which is working, just not safe)

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'my_app_id',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.8'
        });
        FB.api(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/my_fb_page/feed?fields=full_picture,message,story,created_time&access_token=my_access_token",
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    var news = response.data.splice(0,4);
                    console.log(news);
                }
            }
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use the Access Token server-side. Never use Tokens on the client, the App Access Token includes the App Secret - which is called "Secret" for a reason.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Ok, I though that there might be some public access_token which I could use on front-end. Thank you.

Comment: no, access tokens are always meant to be kept secret.

Comment: Follow up question: If I use app-id|app-secret as authentication on front-end and set "Allow API Access to App Settings" in app settings to "NO", is it safe to use it on front-end? This app is for nothing else but to read some FB public page feed. It's not connected to anything and it will never be.

Comment: no, it´s still not safe - for another reason too: if someone hits your page very often, you will hit api limits. the proper way to do this is to use the app token server side (again, it is called "secret" for a reason) AND to cache the results so you don´t need to use the api on every page hit.